# Should paths of #include in the C file and the -I directive given to GCC match?

Tags: c, include, freertos

I am looking at FreeRTOS demo project for an AVR port. The Makefile has paths to the directories where the source files of RTOS are located through an "-I" directive. However, in the **main.c** module of the project #include does not provide any path like this:

```
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
```

So I am not able to understand is that is the "-I" directive required only for linker to find the object files? Does it also mean that once the files are compiled to object code, for GCC they are essentially lying in the same folder if it knows where to look?

I have this confusion because I have seen *#include* statements like these previously:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
```

If GCC already knows the location of **io.h** why include the **"avr"** part in front of it?

Comment: You've got it a bit backwards. `-I` tells the compiler to search that path to find header files. That's the very reason why `#include "FreeRTOS.h"` doesn't need the path. If there was no `-I` then you would need to put the full path in the `#include` (which is bad practice).

Answer (score 0):

When we say

```
#include <foo/bar.h>
```

the compiler usually looks for a file called `bar.h` in a directory called `foo` in one of the places it is configured to look for headers. For example, the standard header search path usually contains `/usr/include', so a file 'bar.h' will be found, if it exists, in '/usr/include/foo'.

If you use the `-I` switch like this:

```
-I /usr/include/foo
```

you could alternatively write

```
#include <bar.h>
```

because you've subsumed the directory `foo` into the compiler's header search path.

However, if `foo` is some kind of library or module, it's probably more expressive to use a variant of `#include` that includes the subdirectory `foo`, rather than manipulating the header search path so that you don't have to.

For the record, the `-I` switch has no direct effect on linking behaviour.

Incidentally, the variant

```
#include "foo/bar.h"
```

conventionally indicated a file in a directory `foo` in the same directory as the source file. However, modern compilers seem to apply search header paths to these directives as well. I'm not sure whether this is standards-based behaviour, or just compiler writers trying to guess our intentions.